# Is there any different semantics between "(1..4)" and "{1..4}" iteration in Rust?

Tags: rust

I find using `(1..4)`

```
fn main() {
    for v in (1..4) {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

and `{1..4}`

```
fn main() {
    for v in {1..4} {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

gets the same result. Is there any different semantics between "`(1..4)`" and "`{1..4}`" iteration?

Comment: The compiler actually gives a warning when parenthesis are used, but not braces. Interesting. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5c648aff16dcedc4ef90bad46087e087&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: @Akavall that's because there *are* small differences (see the answers), so it wouldn't be possible to replace every braced expression with a parenthesized one, just most of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They produce the same iterators. You can even omit parentheses/braces:

```
fn main() {
    for v in 1..4 {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

You can enclose an expression with `()` or `{}` in general. There is a difference however: `{}` creates a block and you can write statements (like `let`) in it. There is also a very subtle difference in how expressions are parsed. **Edit**: I found [a blog article that describes another difference in how coercion and borrowck works](https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/).

Usually `()` is preferred if you don't need statements.

Answer (score 6):

There's no real useful difference. Both parenthesis and braces count as a single expression and function to alter the precedence. I'm pretty sure they have slightly different parsing rules, but at that point I'd guess there's a cleaner way of writing the code.

Note that in your examples, the idiomatic way would be to use *neither*:

```
fn main() {
    for v in 1..4 {
        println!("{}", v);
    }
}
```

When needed, I feel I've only ever seen parenthesis used, never braces:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (1..4).count());
}
```

---

There are *rare* cases where curly braces provide more power. Since they serve to start a new scope, you can [use them to "manually" transfer ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767108/borrow-pointer-errors-recursively-traversing-tree) in some tricky locations. For the purposes of the simple iterator described, there won't be any visible difference.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing answers I was interested what the difference would be in the mid-level IR.

Even though the braces introduce a new block, in this case there is virtually no difference even in the (Nightly) MIR - the compiler immediately recognizes that the block serves no other purpose than returning a `Range`.